# HOw to get rid of vertical "overflow:hidden" in Slick Slider

Tags: slick.js

All. I am emboding the Online Store PSD design to HTML/CSS. Here is [link](http://html.designmyshop.ru/velomatrix/item_page_view_1.html).
There is an items slider in items page. Every item has configuration icons in the bottom of the it. When you hover on the item, second row of icons appear. Every configuration icon has its tooltip on hover. Let me describe the problem. Now because of Slick slider 'overflow:hidden' property on 'slick-list' block, the second row of icon is not visible fully. BEsides, tooltips are also being trimmed. If If I delete 'overflow:hidden', this problems disappear. But another problem appears. That is, now all slides are visible horizontally which are out of bound.   If you visit the site, you notice in the bottom of the page 2 sliders. The second one has no 'overflow:hidden'. Therefore, everything is visible. But it is not good. If users monitor has high density, it looks very ugly. The first slider is by default. It has 'overflow-hidden' property , therefore everything out of bound is trimmed. I need only get rid of vertical 'overflow:hidden'. Is this possible? Thanks much, in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY2nl.png)

Comment: i think you're actually better off using a `tooltip` library, as i believe your issue could be solved by having a 'container' property be set that changes the position of the tooltip so that you dont encounter the issue with `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand what you mean. Sorry. Can you explain it more detailed? Thank you.

Comment: at most screen resolutions these elements position correctly: http://imgur.com/a/GkYd8

obviously it has some code that detects elements "at the end" so that it displays them differently (position of "tick") http://imgur.com/a/kzwiE

I would suggest finding a library that you can specify a "containment" for these such that it positions the tooltip inside the containment element, than it would be to mess with the slider css to try and allow some elements to overflow and others not to.

Have a look at something like the "containment" option on http://www.tippedjs.com/documentation/options

Comment: @haxxxton What if the content of the "tooltip" or "popup" is slightly taller than the slide container? Changing the position in that case doesn't help.